# An open modal dialog blocked the operation (Cucumber, Watir-WebDriver, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have a problem:
I make a new group at my network webseit and then I will to delete it. When I make it - I see a new window (JavaScript) and I can nothing doing.
How can I whrite my code if I see this window?

I use Watir-WebDriver in Cucumber and I work with Google Chrome.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249287/ruby-watir-clicking-ok-on-javascript-alerts

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps 100% but in my Ruby code I `require "dialogs.rb"` and then call `killjspopup(browser)`
right after loading a new page into Watir::Browser.  This file contains:

```
def killjspopup(browser)

# don't return anything for alert
browser.execute_script("window.alert = function() {}")

# return some string for prompt to simulate user entering it
#browser.execute_script("window.prompt = function() {return 'my name'}")

# return null for prompt to simulate clicking Cancel
browser.execute_script("window.prompt = function() {return null}")

# return true for confirm to simulate clicking OK
browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")

# return false for confirm to simulate clicking Cancel
#browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return false}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solutions listed on the Watir-Webdriver page - http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/?

Answer (score 0):

`browser.alert.ok`

More details at: http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/